# I want Fibonacci string as concat string with previous 2 array element

Tags: php

```
    fibStr(3, ["j", "h"]) ➞ "j, h, hj"

   fibStr(5, ["e", "a"]) ➞ "e, a, ae, aea, aeaae"

   fibStr(6, ["n", "k"]) ➞ "n, k, kn, knk, knkkn, knkknknk"
```

I just want a function that returns a response like : "n, k, kn, knk, knkkn, knkknknk"

Comment: So implement it? You've covered your input and output, start writing code that turns the first into the second, and make a few mistakes until you get it right. That's how we learn. Because unless you have code that doesn't work, to ask a question about, there's nothing for folks to do here?

Comment: like this :  fibStr(5, ["e", "a"]) ➞ "e, a, ae, aea, aeaae"

Comment: The reason you're getting marked down is that you're failing to explain the problem.  SUGGESTION: Maybe you want to create a Fibonacci sequence with TEXT (instead of "numbers") where each successive string is the concatenation of the previous two strings.

Comment: Specifically for Stackoverflow, read through the policy article that explains [which topics you can ask about here](/help/on-topic), which is important to (re)read every now and then, and then also (re)read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) because they help you understand how you should write a post, what information should be in it, and if you don't _have_ that information, you might not have a question that makes sense to post here, and makes more sense on a general programming help forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code will help you:

```
<?php
function fibStr($n, $arr) {
   $resp = $arr;
   for($ij= 2;$ij<$n;$ij++)
   {
    $resp[$ij] = $resp[$ij-1].$resp[$ij-2];
   }
   return implode(", ",$resp);
}
echo fibStr(6, ["n", "k"]);
?>
```